# templated constructor loses rvalue

Tags: c++, templates

I am using a templated constructor in one of my classes

Could anybody tell me why this code compiles with no warnings or errors and yet one line of code (create test with default foo rvalue) just disappears!

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo
{
    int _value;
public:
    Foo()
    :_value(0)
    {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "value[" << _value << "]" << std::endl;
    }
    Foo(int value)
    :_value(value)
    {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "value[" << _value << "]" << std::endl;
    }
    Foo(Foo&& foo) = delete;
    Foo(const Foo& foo) = delete;
    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& output, const Foo& foo)
    {
        output << foo._value;
        return output;
    }
};
class Test
{
public:
    template <typename Type>
    Test(Type&& value)
    {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << " with value[" << value << "]" << std::endl;
    }
    template <typename Type>
    void fn(Type&& value)
    {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << " with value[" << value << "]" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << "//----- test fn with foo rvalue ---------------" << std::endl;
    Test test3(3);
    test3.fn(Foo());
    std::cout << "//----- test with int rvalue ------------------" << std::endl;
    Test test4(1+3);
    std::cout << "//----- create test with default foo rvalue ---" << std::endl;
    Test test5(Foo());
    std::cout << "//----- create test with foo rvalue -----------" << std::endl;
    Test test7 (Foo(1+6));
    std::cout << "//----- create test with moved foo rvalue -----" << std::endl;
    Test test8(std::move(Foo()));

    return 0;
}
```

This produces the following result

```
//----- test fn with foo rvalue ---------------
Test::Test(Type&&) [with Type = int] with value[3]
Foo::Foo()value[0]
void Test::fn(Type&&) [with Type = Foo] with value[0]
//----- test with int rvalue ------------------
Test::Test(Type&&) [with Type = int] with value[4]
//----- create test with default foo rvalue ---
//----- create test with foo rvalue -----------
Foo::Foo(int)value[7]
Test::Test(Type&&) [with Type = Foo] with value[7]
//----- create test with moved foo rvalue -----
Foo::Foo()value[0]
Test::Test(Type&&) [with Type = Foo] with value[0]
```

I am using g++ (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2 with std=c++1y

If it helps, I added a line at the end

```
    std::cout << test5;
```

And the compiler produced a warning

```
    warning: the address of ‘Test test5(Foo (*)())’ will always evaluate as ‘true’ [-Waddress]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Test test5(Foo());
```

It's function declaration, not object creation. For create object you can use for example one of the following

```
Test test5((Foo()));
Test test5 = Test(Foo());
Test test5{Foo()};
```

Comment: Thanks for that, how does it differ from "test3.fn(Foo());" earlier